# _POST parameters mangled when passed via proxy between Apache and HHVM

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, hhvm, apache2.4

I've been working on getting Apache/HHVM/Symfony playing nicely with each other. Majority of everything seems to work but I've ran into a problem when a file is uploaded. The resulting _POST is a single entry rather than the expected array.

The proxy settings are:

`ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/path/to/root/directory/$1`

When using PHP5-FPM (which doesn't mangle the `_POST` parameter) the proxy settings are:

`SetEnvIf Request_URI . proxy-fcgi-pathinfo=1`

```
<Directory "/path/to/root/directory">

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} frontend_dev\.php [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} backend_dev\.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\/plugins\/servlet\/streams
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\/rest\/activity-stream\/

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/mnt/html/dev/prodpad/web/$1 [P]
</Directory>
```

The settings are different based on much trial an error. HHVM would keep saying 404 file not found if the proxy settings were like the PHP5-FPM ones. Forms work fine if there isn't a file so my suspicion is it has to do with HHVM's handling of files in forms but I can't find anything about that.

Do the proxy settings need to change? Or is there something special needed for file uploads with HHVM?

The stack is Symfony 1.4, HHVM 2.4 with Apache 2.4 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in HHVM you can find out more details and the comments around it on this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/1706)